# Unable to show error text in a div after ajax success

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

In my app I want to make a login page. I want do do this login using ajax jquery. If login success it navigate to next page or show a error message in a div.
this is my code

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group radio-inline">
        <label><b>I Am</b></label> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="s"> &nbsp;Student &nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="t"> &nbsp;Teacher &nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="p"> &nbsp;Parent
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email address">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
</form>
<div id="error">

</div>
```

> jquery

```
$(document).on('click','.btn',function() {

    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var category = $("input[name=category]:checked").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "../logincheck.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {category:category,email:email,password:password},
        success:function(data) {
            if (data==='studentlogin') {
                window.location.href = '../student/index.php';
            }
            if(data==='teacherlogin'){
                window.location.href = '../teacher/index.php';
            }
            if(data==='teachersubject') {
                window.location.href = '../teacher/subjectadd.php';
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = 'login.html';
                $("#error").html("Invalis Email/Password");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

> logincheck.php

```
$category=$_POST['category'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$pwd=$_POST['password'];


if ($category == 's') {
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT studentid,studentfname FROM studentinfo WHERE emailid='$email' and pwd='$pwd'");

    $res=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if($res[0]>0){
        $_SESSION['snstudentid']=$res[0] ;
        $_SESSION['snstudentfname']=$res[1] ;

        echo "studentlogin";
        //header("location:student/index.php");
        exit();
    }   
    else{
        echo "error";
        //header("location:pages/login.html");
    }
} elseif ($category == 't') {
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT teacherid,teacherfname FROM teacherinfo WHERE emailid='$email' and pwd='$pwd'");

    $res=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if($res[0]>0){
        $check_subject = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT count(teachersubjectid) FROM teachersubject WHERE teacherid='$res[0]'");
        $subject_result = mysqli_fetch_array($check_subject);

        if ($subject_result[0]>0) {
            $_SESSION['snteacherid']=$res[0];
            $_SESSION['snteacherfname']=$res[1];

            echo "teacherlogin";
            //header("location:teacher/index.php");
            exit();
        } else {
            $_SESSION['snteacherid']=$res[0];
            $_SESSION['snteacherfname']=$res[1];

            echo "teachersubject";
            //header("location:teacher/subjectadd.php");
            exit();
        }
    }   else{
        echo "error";
        //header("location:pages/login.html");
    }
}
```

that error message show for few second and then it goes.I do that error class style display:none;
How I do that?Please help me.

Comment: Obligatory: https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at what this code does:

```
else {
    window.location.href = 'login.html';
    $("#error").html("Invalis Email/Password");
}
```

yes, it redirects the page to `login.html`, then, while the page is loading it puts up the error message, *then* the page load completes and, in your initial login page, the error message is empty.

Remove the line:

```
window.location.href = 'login.html';
```

assuming you are already on login.html.

Comment: another problem is when i enter correct input then is show error message and then goes next page.

Answer (score 0):

If `<div id="error">` has a style of `display:none;`, then its contents will not be displayed. Inside of the ajax success callback, `$("#error").html("Invalis Email/Password");` needs to be `$("#error").html("Invalis Email/Password").show();` to set `display:block;`. See [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/).